# What RSS reader software runs on iOS, Andriod and OS X for someone used to Google reader?

Tags: ios, applications, software-recommendation, rss, google

What software and service functions similarly to an RSS reader which will sync between my Macs, iOS devices, and Android devices?

I am looking for a web view similar to Google reader as well as native client for offline use on all three platforms. I understand there may be no perfect match, so please offer experience and downsides of your solution so others can pick the best solution for themselves.

I'm clearly motivated by [Google reader's close date of summer 2013](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2013/03/a-second-spring-of-cleaning.html) to find a new RSS platform.

Comment: Not a solution...but I'm hoping Reeder may step up to the plate as Reeder already exists for all the platforms in question. I put a feature request in tonight for that as well.

Comment: Reeder is just a Reader client.  It's not got server side capabilities.

Comment: The Reeder folks have tweeted that they're working on something so my guess is we'll be able to continue to use Reeder with either their or some other cloud service. Stay tuned...

Comment: A similar question on webapps [Alternatives for Google Reader](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/41591/12491)

Comment: The webapps question is much more visited and in-depth, but this one looks good as it specifically deals with syncing between several (Apple) devices.

Comment: and currently, their best solution is The Old Reader, which, [according to their blog](http://blog.theoldreader.com/post/45337829605/unexpected-day-what-are-we-gonna-do-about-google), doesn't have iOS/android apps, and isn't prepared for reader's demise.

Comment: @JasonConrad Interesting read regarding Digg's intentions http://blog.digg.com/post/46251309499/whats-next

Comment: @JasonConrad This may also be helpful http://www.replacereader.com/

Comment: @JasonConrad Also the potential return of netnewswire http://blackpixel.com/blog/2013/03/the-return-of-netnewswire.html

Comment: @JasonConrad https://yoleoreader.com/ may be worth considering too.

Comment: @JasonConrad Using Google Spreadsheet http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-an-rss-feed-reader-google-spreadsheet/

Comment: I thought this was important, so added it as a separate answer: As Google Reader will be terminated on **July 1st 2013** **Make sure you save all your feeds using** [Google Takeout](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=backup&passive=1209600&continue=https://www.google.com/takeout/&followup=https://www.google.com/takeout/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just some options I've found a few people discussing. Hope it helps.

- **[Feed Wrangler](http://feedwrangler.net/)**

> David Smith announced that he’s been working on an RSS aggregation service to replace Google Reader.

**[Feedly](http://blog.feedly.com/2013/03/14/google-reader/)**

> ... just announced that if you’re using their app, they plan to seamlessly integrate the syncing to their own sync server.

**[Fever](http://feedafever.com/)**

> ...a self-hosted feed catcher that already syncs with Reeder, as well as quite a few other iOS apps.

**[River2](http://quick.newsriver.org/)**

> River2 is a River of News feed reader with lots of features.

**[NetVibes](http://www.netvibes.com/en)**

> ...one of the most popular web reader, offering a Google Reader-like interface as well as a snazzy iGoogle-like homepage.

**[NewsBlur](http://www.newsblur.com/)**

> ... is also a great option, with an interface that's very similar to Google Reader (and arguably a little more polished). You create an account with them, subscribe to your favorite sites, and can read them on any computer. They even have Android and iOS apps that'll sync your feeds, too

**[Feedbin.me](https://feedbin.me/)**

> See all your feed, summaries and article content side-by-side.

Source: [1](http://shawnblanc.net/2013/03/goodbye-google-reader/), [2](http://shawnblanc.net/2013/03/feed-wrangler/) & [3](http://lifehacker.com/5990456/google-reader-is-getting-shut-down-here-are-the-best-alternatives)

Comment: Great collection! Could you please add links to the different tools?

Comment: @patrix That was my initial plan but feared I had too low of a Stackexchange rank (whatever it's called) I once got that warning. I'll try now, hopefully I can do it.

Comment: @patrix looks like I _can_ add multiple links ^^

Comment: @damx Feedly Pro is coming (premium account however) http://blog.feedly.com/2013/08/26/feedly-pro-available-for-all/

Comment: @damx GMail may also be worth considering http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-use-gmail-as-an-rss-reader/

Answer (score 5):

The closest one I've found is [feedly](http://www.feedly.com/) and [NewsBlur](http://newsblur.com/). They don't have native Mac apps, but have either web apps or Chrome extensions.

The problem is the Mac app. If you look in the App Store, none of those news apps have Android versions (like Reeder). The apps that support iOS and Android (Pulse, Flipboard), don't do native Mac.

Answer (score 2):

There is [fever](http://www.feedafever.com) which works as an RSS combinator with a web-based interface and an API for various clients (e.g. Reeder). You'll need a hosting provider (or Amazon) to run the software on.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an alternative to skim headlines, please give Skim.Me (http://skim.me) a shot. We're a startup releasing to the public soon to help you keep up at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @damx 's great list you can also check out [Bloglines](http://dashboard.bloglines.com/signup). It's funny because I used to use Bloglines until they announced that they were shutting down, so I moved over to Google Reader. 
Now, I've just moved back.

Comment: I tried to sign up for Bloglines and was told I already have an account. I requested a password reset and landed on a NetVibes password reset form. I guess Bloglines is now NetVibes, and thus has already been covered in @damx's answer.

Answer (score 0):

[MultiPLX](http://multiplx.com/index.html) Is An Elegant, Pinterest-Like Web Based RSS Reader that works independently of Google. It will import your feeds from an XML/OPML file while retaining their folder structure. You can share an item across multiple social networks, star them, email a story, discover new feeds to follow, and easily organize your feeds.  MultiPLX, however, provides the option to export your starred or shared items to a JSON file like Google does in Google Takeout.

MultiPLX is in private beta so will have to join the waiting list to get access, but they are fairly fast with the invite codes. Once you’ve gained access to the service, you can either add feeds on the topics suggested by the service, or import your feeds from an XML file. Importing may take a little time, depending on the number of your feeds.

A number of RSS services are trying to fill Google Reader’s shoes, but most of them are paying little to no attention to the information a user would like to import. Many users are faced with the prospect of losing items they’ve shared, liked or starred, and it seems that MultiPLX, with its support to export them, might add support to import them in the future as well, and that would make it the best option for such users.

**Edit
Also worth considering:**

**NewsBar** Is a Minimal RSS Reader with iCloud Sync. It comes in both [Mac](https://itunes.apple.com/app/newsbar-rss-reader/id440472232?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo=4) and [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/app/newsbar-rss-reader/id637670343?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4) flavors, and both offer an attractive take on feed reading.

As yet not available on the Android platform.

[MnmlRdr](https://mnmlrdr.com/):

A lightweight & minimal web-based RSS feed reader. However it is a premium Application - costing $3 per month, prepaid annually ($36/year). For a limited time, you can also select a lifetime membership for a one-time payment of $99.

If you are not satisfied with the service, there is 7 day money back guarantee and a refund of 100% of the subscription fee.

It can be used inconjunction with:

- [ReadKit](http://readkitapp.com/) for OSX
- [Mr Reader](http://www.curioustimes.de/mrreader/) for iPad
- [Reeder](http://reederapp.com/) for iPhone/iPad (read website to keep updated)
- [Read a Fever](http://readafever.prebeta.net/) for Windows Phone
- [Press for Android](http://twentyfivesquares.com/press/) (coming soon)

Other RSS readers worth mentioning include:

- [Feed Rebel](http://www.feedrebel.com/)
- [Red Tree Reader](http://www.redtreereader.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=/)
- [Feeder](http://feeder.co/)
- [NewsCo](http://www.newsco.me/content/go/home)

**Edit:**

[Blogtrottr](http://blogtrottr.com/) delivers updates from all of your favourite news, feeds, and blogs **directly to your email inbox**, giving you the flexibility to stay updated whilst on the go, regardless of whether you are using Android, iOS or OS X.

Answer (score -5):

Try using this one www.gripping.us fully online RSS reader for mac, os, android.

Comment: I would expect an online reader to work on all platforms, that's probably not what the OP was looking for...

Comment: Yes, the OP specified *"as well as native client for offline use".*

Comment: Furthermore, given your affiliation with the domain name listed, this answer is spam. Please see [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) under *"Avoid overt self-promotion."*. You **must** disclose any affiliation directly in your answers -- and, only mention your product or service when it *is* actually an answer. Here, it isn't an answer to the question asked.